# communication between controllers asp.net mvc by viewdata

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

i wanna send an object or at least its ID from a controller to another controller so how can i do it ?
how to send a variable from a controller to another in asp.net mvc

does this instruction solve the problem or it's just for the controller -view communication ?
this is the method in the first controller :

```js
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult login(Utilisateur u)
        {
            if (u.login != null && u.Password != null)
            {
                using (BD_GestionDepences db = new BD_GestionDepences())
                {
                    string x;
                    string hash = GetSHA1HashData(u.Password);
                    x = hash;
                    u.Password = x;
                    u.ConfirmPassword = x;
                    Utilisateur utilisateurV = log_existe("admin", u.login, u.Password);
                    if (utilisateurV != null)
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("admin");
                    }
                    else { ViewBag.ResultMessage = "verifier login et password !"; }
                }
            }
            return View(u);
        }
```

and this is my 2nd controller : i wanna send the user login from the login method in the first controller to the create method in this controller :

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Kendo.Mvc.Extensions;
using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
using mvc_depences.Models;
namespace mvc_depences.Controllers
{
    public class ProjetController : Controller
    {
        private BD_GestionDepences db = new BD_GestionDepences();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        //public ActionResult beforeCreate()
        //{

        //}
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.UtilisateurID = new SelectList(db.Utilisateurs, "UtilisateurID");
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ProjetId,nomP,DateDebut,DateFinPrevue,DateFinReele,etat,Description,UtilisateurID")]Projet projet)
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Projets.Add(projet);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            };
            return View(projet);
        }
        public ActionResult Projet_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            IQueryable<Projet> projets = db.Projets;
            DataSourceResult result = projets.ToDataSourceResult(request, projet => new
            {
                ProjetId = projet.ProjetId,
                nomP = projet.nomP,
                DateDebut = projet.DateDebut,
                DateFinPrevue = projet.DateFinPrevue,
                DateFinReele = projet.DateFinReele,
                etat = projet.etat,
            });
            return Json(result);
        }
        //public ActionResult Index()
        //{
        //    return View();
        //}
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you calling the other controller and what are the signatures of the controller methods? (and no, you cannot use `ViewData`)

Comment: "How are you calling the other controller" !!? i'm not calling any ! i just need to send an int from a controller to another (i.e when the user log in i send his login to the "ProjectController" to put it as a foriegn key when this user create a new project (i have an object called project))

Comment: You question states _how to send a variable from a controller to another_ (another what?)

Comment: how to send a variable from a controller to another  controller

Comment: Read my first comment and edit you question to include the code I requested

Comment: okey i edited my post :)

Comment: Are you wanting to pass a value from the `Create()` POST method to the `Index()` method? And if so, which value?

Comment: i want to pass the login value from the login method in the userController to the Create post method in the ProjetController

Comment: Then you need `return RedirectToAction("Create", "Project", new { id = u.login }); and the Create method need to be `public ActionResult Create(int ID)` (assuming the value of `u.login` is typeof `int`) But its very unclear what you would be trying to achieve with this code.

Comment: where should i put the "  return RedirectToAction("Create", "Project", new { id = u.login }); " ! in the login method ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109291/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-kokomoi).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use **ViewData** for send a variable from a controller to another controller.

Can be perform with On successful authentication, call the following method

```
return RedirectToAction("ActionName", "ControllerName", new {variable1 = value1, variable2 = value2/*...etc*/});
```

Answer (score 1):

hey guys finally my problem is solved :D !!!
i used the TempData it works like ViewData and ViewBag but its for communication between controllers